# Rails def as_json(_opts = {}) conditional attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is possible to conditionaly render a attribute on  def as_json(_opts = {}) method?

because, here is the issue I'm trying to render user address attr if is not blank otherwise the react spit out an error so, I would like to just conditionally render the attribute if the user creates the address.

```
  def as_json(_opts = {})
     response = {
      id: id,
      email: email,
      avatar: avatar

    }

    if self.location.address == !nil
      address = self.location.address
      response.merge(address: address)
    end
    response
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The condition is always `false` because `!nil` becomes `true`, so your condition checks `if self.location.address == true`. The `address` field is a string or a `nil` I believe. Here are several options to construct it.

```rb
# Check if an address is not nil but it allows blank a string
if location.address != nil
# The same but more Ruby-ish way
unless location.address.nil?
# Skips empty strings too
unless location.address.blank?
# The same but inversed
if location.address.present?
```

You can get rid of the condition totally if you apply the [`compact_blank`](https://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/compact_blank) method to the hash.

```rb
def as_json(_opts = {})
  {
    id: id,
    email: email,
    avatar: avatar,
    address: location.address
  }.compact_blank
end
```

You can use safe navigation to make sure if `location` is present `location&.address`.

Comment: Yakov, cool! so compact_blank is a automatic check if the attr is present?

Comment: Yes, but be careful it also removes keys with `false` values

Comment: Another more sustainable option is also to add a serialization layer instead of using `.to_json`. https://thoughtbot.com/blog/better-serialization-less-as-json

Answer (score 0):

Ok, fixed! first you must check the association model

```
  def as_json(_opts = {})

    response = {
      id: id,
 
      email: email,

    }

    if self.location.present?
      address = self.location.address

    end
    response = response.merge(address: address)
  end
```